# How to use sscanf to read a line of csv with continue comma

Tags: c, csv, scanf

I try to parse a line of csv file like this

```
47369758,Ysabel,Rosalie,Matthewson,41,76,47,42,70,83
69054587,Errick,Clareta,,34,67,57,43,27,49
95926740,Gottfried,Farr,Sampson,95,100,61,46,2,85
```

the format is id, firstName,lastname, middlename, hw1, hw2, hw3, midterm1, midterm2, final. And there may did not have middle name,
how do i use sscanf to correctly read second line.

I first use getline to read the file line by line and then put the line inside sscanf to parse to get the correct corresponding value and I read char by char to see if the line have continuesly comma, if there have two comma use the sscanf without the middle name

```
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 1000;
     while(getline(&line, &len, stdin)!= EOF)
     {

        int idNum, final;
        char* firstName = malloc(100);
        char* lastName =malloc(100);
        char* middleName =malloc(100);
        int hw1, hw2, hw3;
        int m1, m2;
        Student * student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
        student->m_scores = malloc(sizeof(Midterms));

        int i;
        int counter =0;

        for (i=0; i< strlen(line); i++){
            if(line[i] == ',' && line[i+1] == ',')
                {counter++;}
        }
        printf("counter: %d\n", counter);

        if (counter == 1)
        {   
            sscanf(line,"%d ,%[^,],%[^,],%0[^,],%d ,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",&idNum, firstName, lastName,middleName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);

        }
        else{

            sscanf(line,"%d ,%[^,],%[^,], %[^,],%d ,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",&idNum, firstName, lastName, middleName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);

        }
```

here is my code to read the line without the middle name

```
sscanf(line,"%d ,%[^,],%[^,],%d ,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",&idNum, firstName, lastName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);
```

here is my code to read the line with middle name

```
sscanf(line,"%d ,%[^,],%[^,], %[^,],%d ,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",&idNum, firstName, lastName, middleName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);
```

here is my actual results

```
47369758,Ysabel,Rosalie,Matthewson,41,76,47,42,70,83
69054587,Errick,Clareta,,41,76,47,42,70,83
95926740,Gottfried,Farr,Sampson,95,100,61,46,2,85
```

here is expected result

```
47369758,Ysabel,Rosalie,Matthewson,41,76,47,42,70,83
69054587,Errick,Clareta,,34,67,57,43,27,49
95926740,Gottfried,Farr,Sampson,95,100,61,46,2,85
```

Comment: *How to use sscanf to read a line of csv with continue comma* – in a creative way.

Comment: sscanf(line,"%d ,%[^,],%[^,],%d ,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",&idNum, firstName, lastName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);

Comment: You don't want to use `%s` or `%[]` without specifying a length.

Comment: Minor: `char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 1000;
     while(getline(&line, &len, stdin)...` is incorrect.  Use `size_t len = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value returned by `sscanf()` anyway.  Your trick of using the line counter is intrinsically fragile and not extensible to handle tens of students, let alone hundreds or thousands or more.  What you need to do is more like:

```
int rc = sscanf(line, "%d , %[^,], %[^,], %[^,],%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d",
                &idNum, firstName, lastName, middleName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);
if (rc == 10)
{
    /* All present and correct */
}
else if (rc == 3)
{
    /* Problem at middle name — presumably it is missing */
    rc = sscanf(line, "%d , %[^,], %[^,],,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d",
           &idNum, firstName, lastName, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &m1, &m2, &final);
    if (rc != 9)
    {
        /* Misformatted still — there is an irresolvable problem with this line */
    }
    else
    {
        /* All except middle name present and correct */
        middlename[0] = '\0';
    }
}
else
{
    /* Misformatted — there is an irresolvable problem with this line */
}
/* Process information here — unless you did it at the 'present and correct' lines */
```

When there's an irresolvable problem, you can report the error, quoting the full line (which you can't do if you don't use `getline()` plus `sscanf()` — that's why using the combination is recommended).

When there isn't an irresolvable problem, you can proceed to copy the data into the recently allocated structure(s).  You could decide that you'll handle more return codes, applying appropriate corrections to the data.  Remember, `sscanf()` stops parsing at the first failure.

All the string-based inputs should be limited — since you seem to allocate 100 bytes, you should be using `%99[^,]`.  You could consider whether names are allowed to contain spaces — and if not, you might use `%99[, ]` or even `%99[^, \t\n]` or similar (and you might consider adding a space between the scan set and the following comma so that any trailing white space after a name is not scanned (like the space before the scan set skips over any white space before the name.  Arguably, that's letting ill-formatted data be processed.  That's not automatically a bad thing.  (It's Postel's Law, or the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): *The principle is also known as Postel's law, after Jon Postel, who wrote in an early specification of TCP: TCP implementations should follow a general principle of robustness: be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others.*)

You could also devise a scheme based on `strcspn()` to identify characters between commas.  You'd process each field into a string, and then convert the string to a number when appropriate (and validate the numbers: negative scores, scores over 100, etc, are probably not valid).  This is the most flexible scheme.  It can also protect you from integer overflows, which `sscanf()` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* do `middleName = NULL;` before calling `sscanf()`. You need to provide a valid pointer to the memory to hold the middle name. If the line has an empty middle name, it will fill it in with an empty string.

There's no need to read the line character by character first. Just let `sscanf()` do its job.

Comment: thank you for answer but even though i delete the middleName = NULL; it still can not read the correct output after the middlename part, i read char by char because there have two condition with middlename, I have to cout the comma in the line, and apply different sscanf

Comment: Did you allocate memory for `middleName` with `malloc()`?

Comment: I think you need to post more of your program, to show how you're declaring and initializing all the variables.

Comment: Then there's no reason why it should show `(null)` there. Post your code.

Comment: the other part work find with middlename, I just wonder the sscanf how to parse continue comma

Comment: What do you mean by "continue comma"? That's not good English. Do you just mean 2 commas next to each other? `scanf()` just writes an empty string into the target variable.